# Binding pointers in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, pointers

At some point in my code I set `UIImageView *` `imageView.image` to `UIImage *` `myImage`. From this point I would love to view changes of `myImage` in `imageView`.

On any `myImage` change, I want to `imageView` to show `myImage`. Hope you understand. Thank you.

-- Edit 1 for better explanation.

At some point in code, i set imageView's image to `myClass.image`. And from this point I want to `imageView` react on any change of `myClass.image`. For example `myClass.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo"];`. Both `imageView` and `myClass.image` are properties with retain. Now, when I change the `myClass.image`, I also have to set `imageView.image = myClass.image` to see new image in image view.

Comment: Please explain properly.

Answer (score 2):

Take a [look at KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Add an observer to the `myClass.image` property and when it changes, update your `imageView`. The code would look something like :

```
// To add the observer
[myClass addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"image" options:0 context:0];


// And to listen for changes
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"image"])
        myImageView.image = object.image;
    else
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I really need set imageView's image once. There is many imageViews and images in my project. I want to imageView to point to some object which can be changed... Maybe some pointer to pointer...

Comment: You can't do what you're trying to do - `UIImageView` takes a pointer to a `UIImage` - it does't take a pointer to a pointer to a `UIImage`. Why do you _need_ to set the image once - what's wrong with updating the image pointer of the imageView?

Comment: imageView is in cell. The cell can be dequeued (recycled) before image is re stetted.

Comment: Then it's up to you to stop listening for changes when the cell is dequeued :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a utility class for this a while back, and so you can download it [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25258177/Binding.zip) from my dropbox.

The syntax is like this:

```
[self bind:@"myImage" toObject:imageView keyPath:@"image"];
...
[self unbind:@"myImage" fromObject:imageView keyPath:@"image"];
```